# Uploading managed package (test run step) seems much slower after Summer '14 release

Tags: managed-package, isv, unit-test, upload, summer14

I just started an upload of a patch release from a patch org and have the feeling that the speed for test executes significantly degraded after the recent Summer '14 upgrade.

Did you experience similar slow downs?!

I am on NA14 and it feels like 10 times slower.

Comment: I've noticed that for several (but not all) tests with database involvement (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE). I'm seeing increases from 10-15sec to 7-10min for single test methods on EU0/EMEA. No problems on NA14 yet. This is true for tests executed with the dev console. I have not tried an upload with the summer release yet.

Comment: The problems seem to be resolved. Both manually executed tests and tests during a package upload are running with expected performance (tested on EU0 and NA14).

Comment: I'm experiencing this now on the NA10 instance...  Very frustrating.  Do we know a cause, yet?